# My boyfriend is Turkish citizen but has a green card. Does he need a visa to visit me in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, turkish-citizens

My boyfriend is Turkish citizen but he has a green card as his mother is a teacher. Does he need a visa to visit me in the UK?

Comment: Of course, why would **US** greencard change anything?

Comment: @vartec: The question is actually not that stupid. UK e.g. waive in some cases transit visa requirements for US green card holders.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: interesting, however, not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, the only thing that matters in this case is nationality. US green card in this case only serves as a proof that he's residing in US legally.

[UK Border Agency website provides details](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/visa/).

> This page explains whether you will need to obtain a visa before you come to 
>   the UK as a general visitor.
>
> You will need a visa if you:
>
> - are a visa national (see 'More information' below); or
> - are stateless (you do not have a nationality); or
> - hold a non-national travel document (a travel document which does not give you the nationality of the country that issued it); or
> - hold a passport issued by an authority that is not recognised in the UK.

The long list of "visa nationals" contains Turkey.

Or you can use *"[Do I need visa?](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/)"* form, which yields following result:

[image]

Comment: Also, this is very useful: http://www.doineedavisafor.com/visa/turkish-citizen/united-kingdom